# Route Not working for Module Federation Apps Created Using Nx workspace

Tags: angular, angular-routing, nrwl-nx, angular-module-federation

Routes are not working in remote Application when we use Module Federation, however when we are running the remote seperately they are Working , I have Done Module Federation using Nx framework

I am using Nx framework, new to it and learning.
I have created one shell Application in Angular ( @ localhost:/4200)
then create a remote Application ( @ localhost:/4201)

I can route to remote Application, and it is working
for example http://localhost:4201/auth/login

but when running that application as a remote in Module Federation I am getting Route Error
That is
http://localhost:4200/customer-portal/auth/login giving Error

I have committed commited whole code at
https://github.com/sjaauirs/ShubhApps/tree/main/ShubhApps

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution : Instead of defining Routes in App.Routes.Ts define route in entry.routes.ts